# Building d-max-heap bottom-up

Tags: c++, heap

I have problem when I try to build a d-max-heap bottom up. The code works when I use low random numbers in the heap, but does not work when I have large numbers in the heap. The problem is probably in my buildBottomUp function. I am not sure if I have understood what the right way to build a bottom up heap is. This is my code:

This is my header file

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

template <typename Comparable>
void buildHeapBottomUp(Comparable arr[], int n, int d){
    int current = 0;
    for (int i = n-1; i > 0; i--){
        current = i;
        comparable++;
        while (arr[current] > arr[(current - 1) / d]){
            swap(arr[current], arr[(current - 1) / d]);
            current = (current - 1) / d;
            comparable++;
        }
    }
}

template <typename Comparable> 
bool checkIfHeap(Comparable arr[], int n, int d){
    bool dMaxHeap = true;
    int current = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        current = i;
        if(arr[current] > arr[(current - 1) / d]){
            dMaxHeap = false;
        }
    }
    return dMaxHeap;
}

template <typename Comparable>
Comparable removeFromHeap(Comparable heap[], int n, int d){
    int current = n;
    int numberOfChildren = d; 
    comparable = comparable + 1;
    while (heap[0] < heap[numberOfChildren]){
        swap(heap[0], heap[numberOfChildren]);
        numberOfChildren = numberOfChildren--;
        comparable = comparable + 1;
    }
    Comparable largest = heap[0];
    swap(heap[0], heap[current]);
    return largest;
}

template <typename Comparable> 
void sortUsingBottomUpConstructionOfHeap(Comparable arr[], int n, int d){
    comparable = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int counter = n;
    Comparable *tmp = new Comparable[n];
    while (i < n){
        Comparable largest = removeFromHeap(arr, counter, d);
        counter--;
        tmp[counter] = largest;
        buildHeapBottomUp(arr, counter, d);
        i++;
    }
    counter = n - 1;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++){
        arr[k] = tmp[counter];
        counter--;
    }
}
#endif
```

This is my main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;

int comparable = 0;

int main(){    
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n;
    int d;
    int insertValues = 0;
    int *arr;
    int maxValue;

    cout << "How many elements do you want in your D-Heap? " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "How many children do you want in your D-Heap? " << endl;
    cin >> d;
    cout << "Choose max value in your D-heap ";
    cin >> maxValue;
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    arr = new int[n];

    fillArrayWithRandomNumbers(arr, n, maxValue);
    cout << "Array before build\n" << endl;
    /*for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << ", ";
    }*/    

    }
    comparable = 0;
    buildHeapBottomUp(arr, n, d);
    if (checkIfHeap(arr, n, d)){
        cout << "\n\nArray after build Top down" << endl;
        cout << "You got" << " " << comparable << " " << "comparison when you build max-heap\n" << endl;
        /*for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << ", ";
        }*/
        comparable = 0;
        sortUsingBottomUpConstructionOfHeap(arr, n, d);
        cout << "\n\nArray after sort Top down" << endl;
        cout << "You got" << " " << comparable << " " << "comparison when you sort max-heap\n" << endl;
        /*for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << ", ";
        }*/
    }
    else{
        cout << "the build function for Bottom up do not work!" << endl;
    }
    cin.ignore();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```